# ffserver: bind(port 8090): Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, ffserver

I install at myself Ubuntu server ffserver and try to run it with default config and get this error:

bind(port 8090): Address family not supported by protocol

I tryed to change address (8082, 8083) but it not works too :(

Any suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address family should be AF_INET in case IPv4 or AF_INET6 in case IPv6.
It seems that the sin_family member of the address struct is not assigned a valid value.
Please check it.